# Custom input - Redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have the following CustomInput component:

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomInput = props => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <label className="form-label">{props.title}</label>
    <input
      className="form-input"
      name={props.name}
      type={props.inputType}
      value={props.content}
      onChange={props.controlFunc}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
    />
  </div>
);

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  inputType: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'number']).isRequired,
  title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  controlFunc: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  content: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.string,
    React.PropTypes.number,
  ]).isRequired,
  placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
};

export default CustomInput;
```

And this is my form:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import CustomInput from '../components/CustomInput';

const renderMyStrangeInput = field => (
  <CustomInput
    inputType={'number'}
    title={'How many items do you currently own?'}
    name={'currentItems'}
    controlFunc={param => field.input.onChange(param.val)}
    content={{ val: field.input.value }}
    placeholder={'Number of items'}
  />
);

class ItemsForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className="container" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Nuevo Pedido</h1>
        <Field name="myField" component={renderMyStrangeInput} />
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary input-group-btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ItemsForm.propTypes = {
};

ItemsForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'Items',
})(ItemsForm);

export default ItemsForm;
```

I can render my component, but there are some issues with the content type. First, if I set the `CustomInput` to accepts numbers I get:

```
he specified value "[object Object]" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

Second, if I set the `inputType` to text, it renders a:

```
[object Object]
```

so, the console is giving the following warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `content` supplied to `CustomInput`.
```

How can I set the content properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are trying pass strings as objects

```
<CustomInput
    inputType="number"
    title="How many items do you currently own?"
    name="currentItems"
    controlFunc={param => field.input.onChange(param.val)}
    content={field.input.value}
    placeholder="Number of items"
  />
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was with the content. I can send object via the rest of the props, but I needed to pass just the `field.input.value`. I am trying to lead with this custom components for `redux-form`, and it is not clear for me how to pass the `content` and `controlFunc`, i.e now I changed the prop sent to content and the warning is solved, but I cannot change the value of the input :( maybe the param needs to be passed in other way

Comment: First thing I have noticed were Strings and I focused on them, but yes also content property seems to accept not object but String or Number :)) good luck with further coding!

Comment: `{param => field.input.onChange(param.val)}` this didn't worked for me, but `{param => field.input.onChange(param.target.value)}` went fine.

Maybe it's because of the newer version?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing object via props and you must pass string or number.

```
content={{ val: field.input.value }} // no!
content={field.input.value} // yes! :)
```

Comment: Yeah! it solved the warning and problem. But, now I cannot change the value inside the input, do you know why?

Comment: I was first :( :DD

Comment: @FacundoGFlores the "controlled input" is the word for You :) [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html). When You pass value to input by props object, you must give onChange method to input to change that passing object.
Solution 1: rename "value" to "defaultValue",
Solution2: read about controlled input :)